# Creating a named range in adjacent cells based on criteria in other cells

Tags: vba

I have the following code... It should go through my table, picking out where column B has the value 'OSI' and column C has the value 'Notifications'. There are three rows which match this criteria.

From this I want to create a named range called 'Notif' that spans the corresponding columns from D to F for those rows, not including the B and C items.

```
Set NotifRng = sht.Range(sht.Range("B1"), sht.Range("C" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
counter = 0

For Each cell In NotifRng 'loop through the range of features
    If cell.Value = "Notifications" And cell.Vaue = "OSI" Then
        counter = counter + 1
        If counter = 1 Then
            Set rng = sht.Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 3))
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, sht.Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 3))) 'build the range
        End If
    End If
Next cell
Debug.Print rng.Address
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "Notif", rng
```

When I run the above code, only the first row returns, not all three. What am I doing wrong? I am not getting any error messages...

Any help would be very very very much appreciated!

Comment: `If cell.Value = "Notifications" And cell.Vaue = "OSI" Then` the cell value can't be both at the same time - do you mean to use `OR`?  Also second value is missing the `L` - Value not Vaue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `If cell.Value = "Notifications" And cell.Vaue = "OSI" Then`, because the `cell.Value` cannot be both "Notifications" and "OSI".

Furthermore, you only need to loop through the first column of the range, thus: `For Each cell In notifRng.Columns(1).Cells`

The `counter` variable is not needed, if you check whether `rng` is assigned or not. At the end it is a good idea to check the `rng` again, before printing its address - `If Not rng Is Nothing Then Debug.Print rng.Address`

If this is the input:

[image]

Then running this code:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Worksheets(1)
    Dim notifRng As Range

    Set notifRng = sht.Range(sht.Range("B1"), sht.Range("C" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Dim rng As Range

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In notifRng.Columns(1).Cells
        If cell.Value = "OSI" And cell.Offset(columnoffset:=1).Value = "Notifications" Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = sht.Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 3))
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, sht.Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 3)))
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then Debug.Print rng.Address

End Sub
```

Would deliver this:
`$C$3:$E$3,$C$5:$E$5,$C$9:$E$9`

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you.  It does away with the `counter` to see if a range has passed and checks the status of the `Rng` variable instead.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim NotifRng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With sht
        Set NotifRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each cell In NotifRng 'loop through column B.
        If cell.Value = "Notifications" And cell.Offset(, 1) = "OSI" Then 'Check value in column B & C.
            If Rng Is Nothing Then 'If Rng doesn't contain a range then set one (columns C & E)
                Set Rng = sht.Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 3))
            Else 'If Rng already contains a range(s) then add to it.
                Set Rng = Union(Rng, sht.Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 3))) 'build the range
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "Notif", Rng

End Sub
```

Hmmm - trying to delete my answer as @Vityata explains better, but it's not letting me.